# How to set the query timeout period of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, timeout, connection-timeout, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I seems to encounter query timeout problem when this error appears in Apache IoTDB Version 0.13.0:

```
org.apache.iotdb.db.exception.query.QueryTimeoutRuntimeException: Current query is time out, please check your statement or modify timeout parameter.
```

Therefore I need to check the current settings of timeout time period, but I did not find how to check this.

I wonder how to check and reset the query timeout period? (Right now I only know how to set the parameter of connection timeout.)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the path IoTDB-engine.properties in Apache IoTDB, and there is a parameter called "query timeout". You can use this parameter to check the query timeout period time.